# Obtain XML file POST request to parse with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, post, nokogiri

I have a client that is sending XML for my site to parse. I am typically a PHP guy and understand how to parse it via PHP, but I am not sure how to do the same with Ruby. The client said they are going to post their XML file to my server (i.e. code below)

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d "@/path/to/file.xml" my-web-address.com/parser
```

and then the parser handler page needs to be able to detect that a file was sent to it, and parse it. Does this mean that Ruby simply looks for any POST request? What do I call to get the POST content (XML file) into a variable to mess with it?

I'm using Nokogiri to parse the XML.

```
doc  = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
```

Appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that you already get the XML contents in `params`, as a hash. But if you stil prefer to use Nokogiri:

```
def some_action
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(request.body.read) # or Nokogiri::XML.fragment
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are using rails it should "decode" the xml POST request. example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<group id="3">
  <point>
    <value>70.152100</value>
  </point>
  <point>
    <value>69.536700</value>
  </point>
</group>
```

would be available in the params variable

```
params['group']['id'] # => '3'
```

if you're dead set on using nokogiri it sounds like you have malformed xml, try:

```
Nokogiri::XML.fragment(request.body.read)
```

Comment: Thanks! Everything is all set now.

Comment: This feature was removed from Rails core starting with Rails 4. We need to use a separate gem now https://github.com/rails/actionpack-xml_parser

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution without external gems:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  def postxml
    h = Hash.from_xml(request.body.read)
    Rails.logger.info h

    render status: 200
  end

end
```

Comment: I've improved upon this slightly by adding an `.with_indifferent_access`  onto the end of the `Hash` line, to allow indifferent access.